# How to allow for dynamic CSS with multiple clients

Tags: css, sass

I have a situation where I want provide clients an area where they can customize font colors, sizes, accent colors, and a few other customizations beyond our current static themes.  Does anyone have experience doing this?  I'm playing with SCSS now to see if that will help me get the job done but it looks like CSS "variables" may be more helpful as I can use Javascript afterwards to replace the "variables" with data that I get back from our database.  What would be the best solution to allow data retrieved from the database to create/edit dynamic stylesheet?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I sense a question is formulating but I could not find it here... Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question

Comment: I will read that in just a moment, in the meantime I updated the question to include...an actual question.  Thank you!

Comment: I have done exactly that by having the server generate the plain-CSS stylesheet from the user's preferences. Since a server-side technology can generally respond to any sort of request, I put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/css/user.css">` in the pages then, rather than an actual user.css file, I mapped `/app/css/user.css` to a server-side process which sent a `text/css` response with the dynamically generated stylesheet. (I did caching too, but that's another story)

Comment: Asking about the best solution is likely to lead to opinion-based answers - which is outside the community guidelines.  I encourage you to read the page and improve this question before if gets downvoted.

Comment: Using custom css variables is great for that, you can reference the variables inside your common css file and define them on the html in a `style` tag depending on the user configuration and your css file will have access to them.